# Finding extrema with multiple constraints without Lagrange multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Find the maximums and minimums of $z = 15x+14y$ with constraints $0 \leq x \leq 10, 0 \leq y \leq 5, 3x+2y \geq 6$

I obviously can't take the partial derivatives of inequalities, so I'm at a loss here as my brain simply can't analyze/visualize 3 simultaneous constraints on the graph at once. What is the easiest/most efficient way of analyzing this system?

Comment: see https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cudmllkhuk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a linear programming problem.

Step 1: graph the constraints.

Step 2: find any corner points.

Step 3: evaluate $z$ at the corners.

Step 4: pick winners and losers.

Alternatively, parameterize the boundary and apply the closed interval method on each boundary segment. But, given that the objective function is linear this hardly seems necessary.